# Creating deb file: hidden files specification by `install` file

Tags: debian, compiling, packaging

I'm creating a deb-file and enumerating the files and paths I need to have in the package using the `install` file. It looks like

```
dir1/* path1
dir2/* path2
...
```

But in a result `deb`-file there are no hidden files from `dir1` and `dir2`. It looks like `*` doesn't match hidden files.

How could I match them apart from specifying each one explicitly?

Comment: I think "dir1/.* path1" would work but I'm unsure

Comment: @porton: In that case I will have only hidden files right under `dir1` copied. This won't include not-hidden ones and hidden files from nested directories

Comment: @zerkms This is using `dh_install`?

Comment: @jordanm: yep..

Comment: side note: it's unusual to package dotfiles.

Comment: I suggest you to use both "dir1/* path1" and "dir1/.* path1"

Comment: @jordanm: side note: it's `.htaccess` ;-)

Comment: @zerkms a single file can be added explicitly. They don't have to be globs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The globs used by `dh_install` are perl globs, which are modeled after csh globs. These do not match hidden files by default. In order to get all files, including hidden files, you will need to use two globs. Here is an example:

```
dir1/.* path1
dir1/* path1
```

Update: It has been pointed out in comments to this answer that .* matches `.` and `..`. Since perl's globbing doesn't offer anything to avoid this situation, the dotfiles will need to be added explicitly.

```
dir1/.htaccess path1
```

Comment: It leads to `cp: cannot copy a directory, ./public/.., into itself,` error

Comment: `dir/.*` is horrible as it includes `.` and `..`. Try `dir/.??*`

Comment: @Dennis Kaarsemaker: `dir/.??*` will not match say `.a`, but anyway, thanks for the help - I decided to specify that single file explicitly

Comment: @zerkms - I updated the answer based on these comments.

Comment: seriously? `.a`? What crackpot software is so braindead that it uses filenames this non-descriptive?